# EaseUS partition manager terminated abruptly, leaving HDD partition to be unusable

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, easeus-partition-manager

I was using EaseUS partition manager to extend my drive's capacity by including a 100GB partition into it.
The drive was earlier partitioned as 100GB+831Gb = 1TB(Toshiba HDD) and I was making it a single partition.
But during the process which was taking fairly long to complete, the power went off and it terminated abruptly.
Is there a way I can recover contents of the drive as they were?
I have already tried testdisk, but in vain!
The other option is to try a file recovery software but it will take weeks to sort out, with no guarantee that I will get back all my files! :(

Comment: Your best bet is probably to take it to data recovery specialists and have them try to recover your data.

Comment: Is there no other way because data recovery specialists here in india would charge me a fortune for the volume of data in that partition :(.

Comment: Then just copy it from your backup… you did have a backup before attempting a task like this?

Comment: No I did not backup because I thought the task wouldn't take much time. If I would have had the backup then, this question wouldn't have been here. But yes, after being in a situation like this, I'll always have a backup before attempting any such task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `testdisk` again but with more "tricks", the help pages have several examples, see the "Documentation" section here: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

And if recovering the partition / filesystems doesn't work, then PhotoRec can recover lots of different filetypes. It's by the same author & in the same package as Testdisk: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

There's other tools like Scalpel, Foremost, MagicRescue too...

Or see this link for more info too https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: I'll try and get back to you. Thanks for your reply. :)

Comment: I was able to recover all my files using [gpart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gpart). It detected the entire partition as it is i.e. with all the files with the tree structure; so in a case I did not loose anything.

Comment: @DhruvSingh `gpart` sounds like it does some of the same things as `testdisk`, they both scan disks looking for actual partitions, ignoring whatever the partition table might say. That's great news that it worked so well! Definitely get a backup so you're not worried next time, and you can mark an answer as "accepted" if you want too